# Long run time with FM pt_arq_reqlist_get

Tags: abap, sap-hr

I have a problem while using a loop on function module `pt_arq_reqlist_get` and parameter `IM_Command = 'show_reqlist'` to get all requests for all employees, it's about 3000 employees and I'm looping , problem is that the delay in response if I loop 100 employees it takes about 5 minutes, and when it's 1000 there's no response with time out after 15 minutes. My question is how to handle this bad performance? Or any way else?

Code:

```
REPORT YEH_TEST_LEAVE.

TYPE-POOLS: SLIS.
TABLES: PA0006,PERNR,
  YEH_TEMP_LEAVES.

DATA: MESSAGES      TYPE PTARQ_UIA_MESSAGES_TAB,
      IM_TEAM       TYPE HROBJECT,
      IM_DEBUG      TYPE BOOLEAN,
      EX_AS_OF_DATE TYPE SY-DATUM,
      EX_COMMANDS   TYPE PTARQ_UIA_COMMAND_TAB,
      REQ_LIST      TYPE PTARQ_UIA_REQLIST_TAB,
      REQ_WA        TYPE PTARQ_UIA_REQLIST_STRUC.
DATA: track type YEH_TEMP_LEAVES.

SELECT-OPTIONS:  XCode1 FOR  PERNR-PERNR.
START-OF-SELECTION.

loop at XCode1.
CALL FUNCTION 'PT_ARQ_REQLIST_GET'
  EXPORTING
    IM_PERNR        = XCode1-LOW
    IM_TEAM         = IM_TEAM
    IM_COMMAND      = 'SHOW_REQLIST'
    IM_MODUS        = 'A'
  IMPORTING
   EX_REQUEST_LIST = REQ_LIST
    EX_AS_OF_DATE   = EX_AS_OF_DATE
  TABLES
    EX_MESSAGES     = MESSAGES
    EX_COMMANDS     = EX_COMMANDS.

  WRITE: / XCode1-SIGN,
  XCode1-option,
  XCode1-low,
  XCode1-high.

endloop.
```

Comment: This requires performance analysis the classic way, which is not specific to this function module (it's valid for any ABAP code). I don't know this function module, so I can't say.